# Reading from Postgres SQL in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: postgresql, python

I am trying to read data directly from Postgres to my python environment with the below:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql
conn = pg.connect(database="abcd",user="postgres", password="xxxx")
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * "xyz"', conn)
df.head()
```

But I get the below error when reading:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * "xyz"': syntax error at or near ""xyz""
>   LINE 1: SELECT * "trans"

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify important keyword "FROM":

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * "xyz"', conn)
```

so the right one is:

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM "xyz"', conn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not define anything as pd. So just change pd to psql, and add the table name:

```
df = psql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM tablename', conn)
```